# Write stored procedure parameters to an XML Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a need to take the parameters passed in to a Stored Procedure (SQL 2005) and write those values into an XML column as one xml document.

Looking for an idea on how to start it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's do this thing!

```
select 1 [one],2 [two],3 [three]
from  (select null dummy) t
for xml auto
```

and we get

```
<t one="1" two="2" three="3" />
```

Neat, eh?

You can also experiment with **for xml path** like so:

```
select 1[one],2[two],3[three]
from  (select null dummy) t
for xml path('foo')
```

And the result is:

```
<foo>
  <one>1</one>
  <two>2</two>
  <three>3</three>
</foo>
```

Comment: +1: Without more detail, the TSQL [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx) has numerous options to create XML.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Denis. Now I'm playing with fire.

Comment: @tmercer: Yes, you are playing with fire, so be careful. See [Brent Ozar's blog](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/02/mcm-prep-week-microsoft-exam-70-433-and-70-451/) under the heading "Just Because You Can…." for some great comments on XML in the database.